# How to show Multiple Images inside a Listview?

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I'm trying to show multiple Images inside of List View Item. All Data perfectoly set but When I'm showing multiple images inside of List View Item it show perfectoly when it create but after scrolling the page it show me double images inside of list view item. I'm programmatically create ImageView and add in Linear Layout. Also how to get that ImageView position. I attach Images below. How to fix this bug

This is my Adapter code.

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final ApproveReimbBin item = getItem(position);
    FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    String date = item.getStr_startDate();
    String[] splitDate = date.split("To");

    String profileName = item.getStr_name();
    String profileEmpId = item.getStr_empId();
    String profileType = item.getStr_type();
    String profileAmount = item.getStr_amount();
    String[] childDocument = item.getStr_documents();

    if (cell == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        cell = (FoldingCell) vi.inflate(R.layout.adapter_approvereimburs, parent, false);

        // binding view parts to view holder
        viewHolder.imag_listProfileImage = cell.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        viewHolder.txt_listName = cell.findViewById(R.id.list_profileName);
        viewHolder.txt_listEmpId = cell.findViewById(R.id.list_profileEmpId);
        viewHolder.txt_listType = cell.findViewById(R.id.list_profileType);

        viewHolder.image_childProfileImage = cell.findViewById(R.id.child_profile_img);
        viewHolder.txt_name = cell.findViewById(R.id.txt_profile_name);
        viewHolder.txt_empId = cell.findViewById(R.id.txt_profile_id);
        viewHolder.txt_type = cell.findViewById(R.id.txt_profile_type);

        viewHolder.txt_frmDate = cell.findViewById(R.id.txt_from_date);
        viewHolder.txt_toDate = cell.findViewById(R.id.txt_to_date);
        viewHolder.txt_amount = cell.findViewById(R.id.txt_amount);
        viewHolder.btn_reject = cell.findViewById(R.id.btn_reject);
        viewHolder.btn_approve = cell.findViewById(R.id.btn_approve);
        viewHolder.linearLayout = cell.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_Image);

        cell.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) {
            cell.unfold(true);
            Log.e("suraj", "unfold call");
        } else {
            cell.fold(true);
            Log.e("suraj", "fold call");
        }
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) cell.getTag();
    }

    if (null == item)
        return cell;


    String ImageUrl = ServerUrls.Web.IMAGE_URL + profileEmpId.trim() + ".jpg";

    ImageView image;
    if (childDocument.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < childDocument.length; i++) {

            String doc = childDocument[i].replace("~", "");
            doc = doc.replace(",", "");

            image = new ImageView(mContext);
            image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80, 60));
            image.setMaxHeight(50);
            image.setMaxWidth(50);

            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(imageDocument.trim() + doc)
                    .error(R.drawable.doc_img)
                    .into(image);

            viewHolder.linearLayout.addView(image);
            int lent = childDocument.length;
            Log.e("surajj", "docu " + imageDocument.trim() + doc + " position " + i + " lenth " + lent);
        }
    } else {
        viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(ImageUrl.trim())
            .error(R.drawable.ic_user)
            .into(viewHolder.imag_listProfileImage);

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(ImageUrl.trim())
            .error(R.drawable.ic_user)
            .into(viewHolder.image_childProfileImage);


    if (profileName != null || !profileName.equals(" ")) {
        viewHolder.txt_listName.setText(profileName);
        viewHolder.txt_name.setText(profileName);
    }
    if (profileEmpId != null || !profileEmpId.equals(" ")) {
        viewHolder.txt_listEmpId.setText(profileEmpId);
        viewHolder.txt_empId.setText(profileEmpId);
    }
    if (profileType != null || !profileType.equals(" ")) {
        viewHolder.txt_listType.setText(profileType);
        viewHolder.txt_type.setText(profileType);
    }
    if (profileAmount != null || !profileAmount.equals(" ")) {
        viewHolder.txt_amount.setText(profileAmount);
    }

    if (splitDate != null || !splitDate.equals(" ")) {

        if (splitDate.length == 2) {
            Log.d("suraj1", "fromDate " + splitDate[0] + " toDate " + splitDate[1]);

            viewHolder.txt_frmDate.setText(splitDate[0]);
            viewHolder.txt_toDate.setText(splitDate[1]);
        } else {
            Log.d("suraj1", "onlyfromDate " + splitDate[0]);
            viewHolder.txt_frmDate.setText(splitDate[0]);
        }
    }

    viewHolder.btn_approve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            requestId = item.getStr_requestId();
            reimbursmentId = item.getStr_reimbursementid();
            action = "Approved";
            Methods.showProgressDialog(mContext);
            unfoldedIndexes.clear();
            new asyncSendRequest().execute();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btn_reject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            requestId = item.getStr_requestId();
            reimbursmentId = item.getStr_reimbursementid();
            action = "Rejected";
            Methods.showProgressDialog(mContext);
            unfoldedIndexes.clear();
            new asyncSendRequest().execute();
        }
    });

    return cell;
}
```

This is my Json

```
[  {    "documents": [
  "~\\Upload\\10 Nov 2017\\KB94L636459349491385669.jpg,"
],
"username": "Pranav Khanvilkar",
"empcode": "313395",
"type": "TRAIN / BUS PASS",
"startEndDate": "03-Nov-2017 To 02-Dec-2017",
"requestid": "1916",
"amount": "265",
"reimbursementid": "3",
"applyDate": "11/10/2017 6:22:29 PM"  },  {
"documents": [
  "~\\Upload\\07 Apr 2018\\XHKZU636586950672544266.jpg,",
  "~\\Upload\\07 Apr 2018\\2V44D636586950672674273.jpg,"
],
"username": "Anil Pawar",
"empcode": "313325",
"type": "SALES VISIT",
"startEndDate": "05-Apr-2018 To 06-Apr-2018",
"requestid": "8448",
"amount": "400",
"reimbursementid": "4",
"applyDate": "4/7/2018 10:51:04 AM"  }]
```

This is I'm getting issue.
Before Scrolling Page. [image]

After Scrolling Page. 
[image]

Comment: First of all, stop using listview, and try to use a Recyclerview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code before your for loop.

```
if (viewHolder.linearLayout..getChildCount()>0)
viewHolder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

and after call this for loop

```
if (childDocument.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < childDocument.length; i++) {

        String doc = childDocument[i].replace("~", "");
        doc = doc.replace(",", "");

        image = new ImageView(mContext);
        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80, 60));
        image.setMaxHeight(50);
        image.setMaxWidth(50);

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(imageDocument.trim() + doc)
                .error(R.drawable.doc_img)
                .into(image);

        viewHolder.linearLayout.addView(image);
        int lent = childDocument.length;
        Log.e("surajj", "docu " + imageDocument.trim() + doc + " position " + i + " lenth " + lent);
    }
} else {
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
Now tell me how to get that Image Position/path coz of I want to show in Full ImageView.

Comment: When you are performing this task 
`viewHolder.linearLayout.addView(image);`


set image tag in that if you want path then set path else set the position and perform operation what you need to perform.
Set tag like this:


`ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setTag(position); //also you are able to set path in the tag`

Answer (score 0):

Call this

```
viewHolder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

before your for loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < childDocument.length; i++) {
         ...
    }
```